# MemoryMappedFile - что это?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите, что в итоге такое MemoryMappedFile ?

Я понял так, что это просто интерфейс, который позволяет получать доступ к файлу на HDD - похожим на функции управления памяти в Си - ну типа через указатели.

Так же, при упоминании MemoryMappedFile - говорят об удобстве межпроцессорного взаимодействия через этот общий файл. Меня, как раз интересует этот момент.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что взаимодействие двух приложений или двух процессов одного и того же приложения через этот MemoryMappedFile - все равно будет нагружать жесткий диск постоянным обращением к нему, к записи и чтению, что очень не любят HDD, да и SSD(при записи) - то есть идея настроить межпроцессорное взаимодействие через MemoryMappedFile - это все ровно плохая идея с точки зрения живучести жетского диска, а в случае с HDD - еще и медленное взаимодейтсвие за счет малой скорости HDD на чтение и запись ?

Или я все неправильно понял ?

Comment: Ключевое слово - memory, привязки к жесткому диску может вообще не быть.

Comment: Если  CreateFileMapping выполняется с INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, то файл на диске не используется, этот вариант для IPC (взаимодействие приложений ), видимо, основной.

Comment: @MBo, Спасибо! С MSDN: "В этом сценарии CreateFileMapping создает объект сопоставления файлов указанного размера, который поддерживается системным файлом подкачки, а не файлом в файловой системе." Не могу понять, а что имеется ввиду под " который поддерживается системным файлом подкачки" ? Файл подкачки разве не связан с жесктм диском ?

Comment: Файл подкачки - в памяти, но жесткий диск используется, когда памяти не хватает (c:\pagefile.sys)

Comment: @MBo, спасибо, а я правильно понял, что этот механизм можно использовать только в рамках одного приложения, так как второй процесс ипользует созданный дескриптор из первого процесса ?

Comment: Нет. Вы делаете  CreateFileMapping с INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE и именуете "файл", точнее объект отображения (параметр LPCSTR  lpName), затем получаете указатель на него с помощью MapViewOfFile. Второй процесс делает OpenFileMapping c нужным именем и получает свой указатель на ту же память с помощью MapViewOfFile. Всё, можно обмениваться данными

Comment: MMF это механизм для прямого доступа приложения к данным файла **в файловом кэше ОС** по указателю. Реализуется на уровне управления страницами адресного пространства процесса. Отсюда следует все остальное

Answer (score 0):

MMF вообще может быть не связан с реальным файлом на диске. Чисто виртуальный файл в оперативной памяти, доступный для разных процессов по указателю.
В этом случае, когда процесс-создатель завершается, файл уничтожается. И в других процессах попытка обращения к нему вызовет исключение соотв типа.
Очень интересная вещь для обмена информацией между процессами.